# Accessing variables across packages in Go

Tags: scope, go, package

I have two variables in the scope of `package main`, those would be these:

```
var (
    app Application
    cfg Config
)
```

Now, since the size of my application is starting to increase, I have decided to put each module of the website in its own package, much like a subdirectory as so:

```
/src/github.com/Adel92/Sophie
  + user/   (package user)
     - register.go
     - login.go
     - password.go
  + topic/  (package topic)
     - ... etc
  - main.go (package main)
```

How would I go around around accessing the `app` and `cfg` global variables from other packages? Is this the wrong way to go about it? I have a feeling it is.

In that case, how would I declare functions in their own namespace so I don't have to go crazy with names that are affixed with `user` and `topic` all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Capitalized variable names are exported for access in other packages, so `App` and `Cfg` would work. However, using sub-packages for name-spacing is generally not recommended; packages are intended for discrete, self-contained functionality so it is usually more trouble than it's worth to use them this way (for example, import cycles are strictly impossible, so if you have two sub-packages in this layout that need to talk to each other then you're out of luck).

If you're finding you need to prefix things with `user` and `topic` in order to avoid name collisions, then perhaps the underlying concept should be factored into its own package, and you can create one instance of it for `user` and one for `topic`?

Comment: That would make no sense because user/topic aren't self contained things, they heavily rely on functionality from package main.

Comment: Well since there appears to be no better alternatives, I'll up vote this and accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: If user/topic depend heavily on functionality in main, that indicates that they should belong in the main package. Because you can't have dependency cycles, dependencies should only ever flow "downwards" from main.